# Would be nice to be able to submit linked answers that show as a regular answer

Tags: discussion, answers

I often see questions and think, I know I, or someone else, answered that well in a different question, but the question itself is not really a duplicate.

I usually just add a comment saying "Read this " with a link but it seems to me it would be feasible to add a button here than says "Link an answer".

You could them click that to attach the answer to the current question.

It would then just be displayed in-line in the current page, albeit stored elsewhere in the data-base.

Comment: If one of the answers answers the other question, why wouldn't you mark it as a duplicate? That will help the OP won't it?

Comment: What's the benefit of spending dev time on this when it's easy enough to say, "This answer addresses your question."? Also, integrating this implies that it's an action we want. Is that the case?

Answer (score 6):

The main problem I see to this is that the linked answer *is not an answer to this question*.

If the *question* is a duplicate, we already have mechanisms to handle that. However, you're talking about cases where one answer to *a completely different question* just *happens* to answer this one perfectly.

But that answer *isn't* an answer to this question. The vote counts are based on how well it answers *the other* question. The comments are criticism on how well it answers *the other* question. Any edits, past or future, are based on making it better answer *the other* question.

None of that post history is relevant to *this* question. So really, in the case you're describing, the only thing that's *actually* valuable to answering *this* question is the text body itself, and even *that* only as-written at this particular point in time since potential future edits would be based on the *original* question rather than having any reflection at all on *this* question.

In other words, you're asking for a feature that mostly just copy-pastes the text of an existing answer (with none of the history) and adds a link to the original post (because appropriate attribution is awesome). Which you can easily do by simply copy-pasting the text of an existing answer and adding a link yourself.

Adding this as a feature seems like a lot of work for a rather limited edge case for something that can easily be accomplished with existing tools.

Comment: Ya this was originally a question in the Electrical Engineering-META section  where questions tend to be specific to an application, but the answers are more general in nature... So the question itself is not duplicate, or at least the OP thinks it is not and gets offended, but the answer still helps explain the situation. It gets complicated.

Comment: @Trevor_G I don't know how EESE would/should handle things, but if all answers (current and future) to the linked question would perfectly answer the new one, it should probably be treated as a duplicate anyway.

Comment: This is a relevant feature request for meta sites, where it's common to close questions as duplicates even if they're merely related (e.g. as an [tag:faq] question).